# why does my code not change the column names to lower case?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

[image][![**I have a dataframe new_df with its columns as listed in the picture, I am trying to create a new dataframe df_6  with this dataframe(new_df) having the columns changed to all lower case but when I run the code, I do not notice any changes. please someone should help clarify why***][2]][2]

I have a dataframe new_df with its columns as listed in the picture, I am trying to create a new dataframe df_6  with this dataframe(new_df) having the columns changed to all lower case but when I run the code, I do not notice any changes. please someone should help clarify why

Comment: Well, you keep setting `df_6` to an altered version of `new_df`, over and over. So your changes to the column names aren't going to persist!  I suspect that by the time you display it, it will only reflect the changes made to the final column name.

Comment: I suspect that this isn't the preferred approach (looping through and creating multiple new dataframes, which you discard) anyway. However, I don't know Jupyter.

Comment: But if you want to try it this way, try looping through the columns of `new_df`, setting `df_6` to `new_df.withColumnRenamed(etc)` if `df_6` is null, and to `df_6.withColumnRenamed(etc)` if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Ann in the comments, it doesn't update the column names because you keep assigning `new_df` to a new variable, and each time it sets the original `new_df` because no updates were saved to the `new_df` variable.

If you're keen on creating a new variable, you can use a `select()` with list comprehension.

```
df_6 = new_df. \
    select(*[func.col(k).alias(k.lower()) for k in new_df.columns])
```